# Split arrays into multiple arrays based on string characters

Tags: javascript, algorithm

My Initial array:

```
var mainArray = ['car','incl','arc','linc','rca','icnl','meta','tame'];
```

I want the result like:

```
[['car','arc','rca'],['linc','icnl','incl'],['meta','tame']];
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [ask] and provide [mcve] of your code and explain what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Did you made an attempt ? Perhaps it would be obvious once you really properly write the exact requirement ?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What did you try already? What is the criteria you want to use to separate that array?

Comment: it looks like to groups same letters of unordered strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compact version by using a closure for the sorted character array.

```js
var array = ['car', 'incl', 'arc', 'linc', 'rca', 'icnl', 'meta', 'tame'],
    result = Object.values(
        array.reduce(
            (r, s) => (a => ((r[a] = r[a] || []).push(s), r))([...s].sort()),
            {}
        )
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help